# Problema em inserção no banco de dados por java

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando fazer um app de uma clínica veterinária e segui todos os passos direitinhos para criar o banco de dados, conectar com o eclipse e etc. O programa conecta, mas não insere nada que foi digitado no programa no banco de dados, embora a mensagem mostre que o cadastro foi realizado com sucesso.

```
package BD;
import java.sql.*;


import java.sql.*;

public class BancoDeDados {


    private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bd?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
    private static String user = "root";
    private static String pass = "artpop";
    protected static Connection conexao = null;

    public BancoDeDados(){
        if(conexao==null) conecta();
    }




    public static boolean conecta(){
        try {
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);   
            return true;
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }



    public static boolean desconecta(){
        try{
            conexao.close();
            return true;
        }catch(SQLException e){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

/**************************************DAO**********/

```
package BD;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ClienteDao extends BancoDeDados{


    public boolean adicionarCliente(Cliente c){
        try{
            Statement st =  conexao.createStatement();          
    st.executeUpdate("insert into clientes values ('" + c.getNome_cliente()+"','"+c.getCpf_cliente()+"','"+c.getrg_cliente()+"','"+c.gettelefone_cliente()+"','"+c.getEndereco_cliente()+"');");



        return true;
        }catch(SQLException e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Para tela:

```
continuar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ClienteDao clienteDAO = new ClienteDao();
        try{
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nome.getText(), cpf.getText(), rg.getText(), telefone.getText(), endereco.getText());
        clienteDAO.adicionarCliente(cliente);   
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, nome.getText() + "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!!");
        }catch(Exception er){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Não foi possível realizar cadastro, verifique!");

        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Aparentemente você não está iniciando a conexão, tente utilizar o método conecta().

Comment: Em que momento você inicia a conexao? No codigo, isto não é feito nunca, e portanto, nada será comunicado com o banco. Alem disso, se o metodo `adicionarCliente` retorna um booleano e você não usa, qual o sentido de retornar true e false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua conexão nunca é iniciada, seu método de conexão está retornando true ou false, você deve utilizar o método conecta para retornar a conexão com o banco e aí sim enviar os dados para o seu Banco de Dados. Você pode criar um construtor no seu DAO de Cliente para chamar o método de conexão com o banco de dados toda vez que você instanciar o objeto.

```
public class BancoDeDados {

    public static java.sql.Connection conecta(){
        try {
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);   
            return conexao;
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class ClienteDao {
   private Connection connection;
   public ClienteDao() {
      this.connection = BancoDeDados.conecta();
   }
}
```